# Silverlight 4: Fields disapear in data grid after saving en

Tags: silverlight, wcf, entity-framework

When saving a new entity something strange happens...
I have a data grid with a list of 'Depots' populated using a domain data source.
When the user wants to add a new 'Depot' this is what happens:

```
Depot newDepot = new Depot();
newDepot.Name = "My New Depot";

EditDepot popup = new EditDepot(newDepot); // create the popup and pass the newly created Depot

domainDataSource.DataView.Add(newDepot); // add a new Depot to the datagrid

// handle the popup events
popup.CancelClick += (cancelSender, cancelArgs) =>
{
    if (GridDataSource.DataView.Contains(newDepot))
        domainDataSource.DataView.Remove(newDepot);

    domainDataSource.DomainContext.RejectChanges();
};

popup.Show();
```

The popup constructor then passes the entity to a viewmodel. The viewmodel constructor then creates a new instance of 'ContactInfo', another entity which is linked to 'Depot' (Depot.ContactInfo). After filling in a few properties, the 'Depot' is assigned to a property in the viewmodel and a dataform is used to edit the data. Once the user is happy with the content they will press save. The Depot is added to the context (Context.Depots.Add....) and then the changes are submitted. (It's also worth noting I have tried added the ContactInfo item to the context too, with no joy). The data is saved to the database (via WCF) and everything appears to have worked correctly. The proplem is the datagrid is not displaying the ContactInfo fields, where as it did before the save. As the user edits the data, you can see the datagrid populated behind the popup. If the user refreshes, the data returns. This problem does not happen when the entity is editied.
Now, to throw another spanner in the works... This doesn't happen on all our machines...
We have a build machine and the output does have this problem, however one machine in the building builds a version which does not have this problem! After some investigation, we have found that it appears to be the version of WCF RIA Services. On my machine, I had V1.0 SP1. I Tried V1.0 SP2 and still had the same problem. Now on the machine that works, WCF RIA Services SP1 Beta was installed. After he unistalled this, and installed SP2, the problem occured on his machine.
So, we are relutant to use a beta version in our final release, but unless we can fix this issue we wont have a choice. Does anyone have any ideas? Has anyone seen this issue before?

I have also tried different version of the WCF toolkit with no joy

**EDIT: I've created a simple project to show you whats happening
The project retrieves a load of entities and tries to add one. You'll notice the the 'InnerThing' properties dissapear.
[Link to project](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=9bd01cc5cbbbd17d&resid=9BD01CC5CBBBD17D!318&parid=9BD01CC5CBBBD17D!267)**

Comment: I've changed the issue example to show the problem more clearly. You can put a break point on line 91 in the view model to inspect the entity and confirm that the inner entity is still there, but not displayed in the datagrid.
[Link To Project](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=9bd01cc5cbbbd17d&resid=9BD01CC5CBBBD17D!318&parid=9BD01CC5CBBBD17D!267)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was that the key property was being set in the insert method in the service.
it looks like this change was not reflected in the client. Changing other properties in the service after submit other than the key did work however.